# Expected value of a survival function

Tags: survival, expected-value

So the life length of the system can be calculated by integrating the survival function like this $E[T] = \int_{0}^{\infty} R_T(t)dt$ where $R_T(t) = 1-F_T(t)$ where $F_T(t)$ is the cumulative distribution function. Lets say I have two components, one $Weibull(1,1/2)$-distributed and another component $Exp(1)$-distributed.

- E[T] of both the individual components are equal to 2. What does this
  mean? What unit is the time T measured in?

If we couple them in a serial system we get 
$$
E[T] = \int_{0}^{\infty} (R_{T1}(t)R_{T2}(t))dt \tag{1}
$$ 
and in a parallel system we get 
$$
E[T] = \int_{0}^{\infty} (1-(R_{T1}(t)R_{T2}(t)))dt. \tag{2}
$$
In both cases we get that $E[T] = 0.69$.

Why is this lower than each component individually? I can imagine it in the case with the serial couplings since the system dies as soon as one of the individual components dies, which should be more often since  But with the parallel coupling I thought it should be higher than the individual components. Why isn't it?

Here is some R code I made if it is to some help.

```
survival_fun_weibull = function(x){exp(-x/2)}
survival_fun_exp = function(x){exp(-sqrt(x))}
survival_fun_serial = function(x){exp(-x/2)*exp(-sqrt(x))}
survival_fun_paralell = function(x){1-(exp(-x/2)*exp(-sqrt(x)))}

expected_life_len_weibull = integrate(survival_fun_weibull, 0, Inf)
expected_life_len_serial = integrate(survival_fun_serial, 0, Inf)
expected_life_len_paralell = integrate(survival_fun_paralell, 0, Inf)

print(round(expected_life_len_weibull$value,2))
print(round(expected_life_len_exp$value,2))
print(round(expected_life_len_serial$value,2))
print(round(expected_life_len_paralell$value,2))
```

Comment: Time is measured in whatever unit you like.  It's impossible to tell from the number "2" alone whether it's days, years, picoseconds, or anything else.  Note that all your integrals require a "$dt$" in them.  This is not a trivial matter, because your last integral clearly diverges when a $dt$ is supplied, so something's not quite right.

Comment: I have added dt.  Why is the last integral divergent?

Comment: I guess you mean Exp(1/.2) (or Exp(2) depending on the convention). Your expression for E[T] for the parallel system is wrong, but I'll let you figure out how to do it correctly (easy).